# How many set of indices satisfy these properties ? Counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

Let $v_{k,l}^{(d)}=(i_1,...,i_N)$ where

- $i_1,...,i_N \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^N i_j = d$, with $d \in \mathbb{R}$
- Exactly $k \leq N$ of the indices $i_1,...,i_N$ are equal to $l\leq d-1$

For given $k,l$ and $d$, how many distinct $v_{k,l}^{(d)}$ exist ?

Comment: Do you consider $0$ to be an element of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, I'll make it clear